# Can UNO log more PCB 353b33 accelerometer data points compared to TDS3014B oscilloscope?

Tags: accelerometer, datalogging

I'm currently recording data points from an analog accelerometer(PCB 353b33) using a TDS3014B oscilloscope which has Record Length of 10,000 points at a Sample Rate 1.25 Ga/s. I'm want to record more data points, would it be possible to use UNO as a data acquisition device and record much higher data points than the oscilloscope(>> 10,000)

Answer (score 1):

No way. The UNO has only 2.5kb of RAM, so you can't cache the data points and you would need a very quick link to get the data out. And sampling at 1.25 GigaSamples/s is orders of magnitude beyond an UNO, as its maximum clock frequency is only 16 MHz. An Uno is about $20, while your TDS3014B is around $1500. Sometimes, there's a reason for a different price tag.

Comment: So if I want to log data for a period of time say 10 mins, then would using an uno a good idea considering the trade off's being the lower sampling rate. As the problem with the oscilloscope is that it's a triggered logging device and I need data for a period of 10 mins or more.

Comment: The sampling rate would be significantly lower, and depending on the signal quality you need, it might not be accurate enough (you did not specify what kind of signal you're measuring). And you need the UNO connected to a PC so that you can transmit and store the collected data right away.

Answer (score 1):

For 10 minutes of sampling at 1.25Gsps using 32-bit floats you would need about 3 terabytes of memory. You're not going to even get close to that with a very very powerful desktop. An Arduino...? Dream on. It's never going to happen.

An Arduino has a couple of kB of memory. Plus a slow, crude, ADC. You may get a fraction of a second at its highest sample rate. To stretch it out over 10 minutes you'd be looking at no more than about 800 samples (16 bit values from a 10 bit ADC), so maybe one sample every 1 1/2 seconds.